# How to get the instance id in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

Does anybody know how to get the instance id in Liferay in a class without using the request object?

`exampleportlet_WAR_myportlet_INSTANCE_wI7pYPyS30be`

I need the `wI7pYPyS30be` part

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to get it for specific portlet namespace or you want to generate such id?

Comment: I want to get it for the portlet the method is being called from

Comment: Can you elaborate your scenario why you dont want to use request object?

Comment: I'm trying to get the id in a helper class I made. This class only gets created once and it has no request object

Comment: If you have layout name and portlet name with its position then you can get it from typeSettings of layout

Answer (score 0):

"in a class" does not quite describe what you'd like to achieve. The request holds the context of a portlet, the portlet class itself doesn't hold any members by design. If that portlet calls some other functionality, you might need to explicitly pass the parameter along, after extracting it from the request (as long as you have access to the request).

A bit of sample code, as well as the underlying problem that you're trying to solve, would help quite a lot.

Comment: I was actually modifying the DefaultFriendlyUrlMapper class. That class has access a Map that holds the request parameters. One of these parameters is the p_p_id so I could manually parse it and get the instance id from that. Thanks